# How to Access Cloud Storage files from Angular on Cloud Run

Tags: angular, google-cloud-run

I am deploying an Angular App on Cloud Run with nginx. The application needs to access Cloud Storage bucket that is not public. When I add @google-cloud/storage npm package, it does not play well with ng build so I can't use Client Libraries.

This feels like it should be a solved problem but I can't seem to find anything relevant in documentation. Using any of the JSON API endpoints just gives a 403 forbidden.

Any help is appreciated since I'm out of my depth.

Comment: Whether you are using the default service account for your Cloud Run service or a specific one, this service account should have the correct role (roles/storage.objectViewer) on your bucket.

Comment: I have actually given the service account Storage Admin permissions (more than necessary) and still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you serve your Angular App from Cloud Run (through NGINX) the angular app effectively run on the local browser of the user, and not on Cloud Run. Thus, the access is generated from the user browser.

The best way to achieve that is to create a backend that authenticate the user and then serve the file (or generate a signed URL). This authentication set is mandatory if the file access is restricted. Else you can set the bucket public and forget the authentication part, access directly to the file in GCS.

Comment: I think I understood that but hoped there was an Angular way of masking the request without using things like AngularFire or a backend service

Comment: If you want to authorize your browser app to be authenticated to GCS, you need a secret for this authentication (a service account key file for example). However, because the app run on the browser, you need to have this key there; thus out of control and anyone can access it. Thus it's like if your GCS was public. You need to keep and manage the secret on "a side managed by you", your backend in fact.

Comment: Thank you @guillaume-blaquiere. This does make sense. I have realized that even having an nginx server to serve the storage objects still requires a public bucket. So I'll go with a backend API